# Does Permalink inside h1 tag effects page SEO?

Tags: wordpress, seo, permalinks

In my wordpress blog I found that my Post title are displayed like the following

```
<h1><a href="permalink">Post Title</a></h1>
```

On diving deep I found the code structure as following

```
<div class="post-title">
    <h1>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a>
    </h1>
</div>
```

I wanted to know whether the anchor tag inside the h1 tag will effect my SEO rankings in a bad way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will **not** affect  your SEO rankings in a bad way.

From what I have read on the subject it doesn't hurt nor help your SEO.

So in that case you can go ahead and do it.

From a coding perspective it works well like you have it:

Either with the `div` wrapper or not. I personally like the 1st best.

source: [**here**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/h1.html).